# Post photo to pinterest by API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, post, pinterest

I need to post a photo to my own board in Pinterest via their API.

However, I cannot find any mention in their API documentation of how to accomplish this - https://developers.pinterest.com/

I have tried to search for an approach but found only dated information.

The following script does exactly what I'd like to do, however I want to implement it via Ruby/Rails - http://www.nextscripts.com/pinterest-automated-posting/

Any advice or documentation on how I could implement this functionality would be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I need to do exactly the same now.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this gem handy, though its a bit dated:

https://github.com/bensheldon/staplegun

Comment: You might want to explain why it is handy in your answer, so that other users don't have to click the link

Comment: I am sorry if my comment looks confusing. Per the gem description it solves the posting problem. According to it:
`Easily post new pins to your Pinterest boards`

Comment: Checked that gem, it's no longer working, moreover it is not using API but mechanize gem to login on site as browser and do posting. However maybe it's the only way with pinterest?

Answer (score 0):

There is a project, that helps to create pin automatically via undocumented Pinterest API https://github.com/v-pukman/pinterest_spammer